# How can I tell the difference between a Clicker and a Runner in Listen Mode

Tags: the-last-of-us

I am having trouble distinguishing the difference between a [*Clicker*](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/The_Infected#Clickers) and a [*Runner*](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/The_Infected#Runners) whenever I use Joel's [Listen Mode](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/Listen_Mode).

Basically, I'll run up to what I think is a *Runner*, use my melee weapon then get a large portion of my neck ripped out (epic fail provided below).

> [image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuE60.gif)
> "AHHHHHH! TAKE THE GIRL INSTEAD!!!"

Is there any clear indication or do I have to rely on sound alone?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `Clickers` have an uglier head. And I'd recommend sneaking from behind all the time, even if it's just a human(don't forget that everybody, except for `Clickers` can see your torchlight)

Comment: Novarg, runners can't see your flashlight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clickers have an odd shaped head and make a clicking noise. They also stumble or limp when they walk. Runners walk more normally and appear more human.

Answer (score 0):

Clickers are a bit oddly shaped compared to a runner, the clickers also have sound waves coming from their to represent their clicking. Runners also sprint to their next position after standing in the same place for about 10-30 seconds and the clickers are usually standing still majority of the time but when moving they walk places and do not sprint.

Answer (score 0):

When using listen mode, a clicker will twitch and spasm more times than a runner and if you are brave enough to throw a brick somewhere so that the two types run over to the sound, you will notice that a runner runs like a **normal** human while a clicker does a sort of spasm while moving.